# Merge() and Update() not working properly - C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge two datatables and update the output of that, to the database table. I am using `SqlCommandBuilder` for updating records to the database.

But the records are not getting updated to the table. Below is my code for updating, which is not working.

```
sourceDt.Merge(clonedDt, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
if (da.UpdateCommand != null)
{
   noOfRowsAffected = da.Update(sourceDt);
}
```

Also,zero errors thrown! Code is executed completely.

Later for testing different updating logic, I wrote the below code;

```
DataRow dr = sourceDt.Rows.Find("100");
dr["ColumnName1"] = "someValueshere";
if (da.UpdateCommand != null)
{
    noOfRowsAffected = da.Update(sourceDt);
}
```

The above code is editing a row having **ID** as **100**, with **someValueshere** in its column **ColumnName1**.
And `Update()` for above code is working fine! My database table record is getting updated!

So there is some problem with using `Merge()` and `Update()` together, but I cannot figure it out what it is!

Comment: Is your primary key set on your sourceDt?

Comment: yes, ID column is primary

Comment: How is clonedDt created?  `.Clone()`? or `.Copy()`?

Comment: @ParrishHusband Using .Clone() to create structure then assigning datatype from SourceDt to CloneDt using loop.